# GitLab not listening on ssh port

Tags: ssh, port, gitlab

I've just installed GitLab CE on my VPS running Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS via omnibus, made the following changes to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and re-ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`:

```
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
external_url 'https://gitlab.myserver.com/'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2222
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
```

My Apache VirtualHost configuration is working and I can access the web interface on `https://gitlab.myserver.com/`, where I've added my SSH key, but when cloning/pushing/etc to or from `ssh://git@gitlab.myserver.com:2222/mygroup/myproject.git` I receive

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.myserver.com port 2222: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

`$ ssh -vvv -T -p 2222 gitlab.myserver.com`:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.myserver.com [12.34.56.78] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address 12.34.56.78 port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host gitlab.myserver.com port 2222: Connection refused
```

`$ netstat -tlpn` does not list any process listening on port 2222
`$ sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check` does not produce any errors or warnings (http://pastebin.com/ThCJ0nU7)

Port 2222/tcp is allowed in ufw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to to set up option `gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2222` based on the port where is your `sshd` server running.

Gitlab is not running separate ssh server, if I am right. If you run `sshd` on standard port, just swap to `22`, restart `gitlab` and `sshd` and try again on standard port.

If you insist on running on different port, you need to [modify](http://web.archive.org/web/20170322213038/https://mind.sh/are/news/code/moving-gitlab-to-a-non-standard-port/) also your `sshd_config` and potentially other stuff on your VPS.

Comment: This is correct. Gitlab sets up a special user to do what it does, so it relies on the system ssh daemon. The config for rails is used for internal config.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `Port 2222` and `AllowUsers ... git` to my `sshd_config` and I can use git without any problems -- but neither do I want my other users to be able to use "real" SSH on port 2222, nor GitLab running on my default SSH port.

Comment: Did you try it with normal `ssh`? It should be forbidden by some `ForceCommand` in front of the keys in `authorized_keys`, if I am right.

Comment: With my administrative account I can `ssh` on port 2222 just as on my other ssh port, which makes sense as `/home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys` is loaded, which does not contain anything else but my ssh key